# How to specify what port RDP responds to?

Tags: remote-desktop, cygwin, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I need to figure out a way to force `RDP`(Remote Desktop) to respond to a specific port Instead of a RHP(Random High Port). I am not asking how to change what port `RDP` "Listens" on, but rather the opposite.

I am attempting to set up an experimental Forward/Reverse `SSH` Tunnel between two systems.  I am using a third system as a Pivot point to hide my IP on the forward tunnel.  But I want the system I am Remoting into through the Forward SSH Tunnel to send the response through a separate reverse `SSH` tunnel to a "Specified" port instead of a RHP.  The basic idea is I want to be able to control what ports I want listening and or receiving, and I don't want anything to be random.  With that said here is a snapshot of my set up.

**Edit:** All the IP addresses in the image have changed which will make it confusing later on when you read the logs I edited into the question.  The new IP addresses are:

- **KGRAVES - 10.0.10.113**
- **DEVILSMILK - 10.0.10.121**
- **DUCLAW - 10.0.10.120**

[image]

As you can tell on the last step my `RDP` session is being sent back through the Reverse `SSH` Tunnel like I want it.  So I have two pipes for my `RDP` session. But it is sending it back on a RHP and I can't figure out how to tell it to send it to a specific port, say `:44444` for example.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I need this done a specific way.  These are the ports I **Have** to use.  I have already set up `Duclaw` to listen for `RDP` on port `1337` instead of `3389`. **I know that this isn't by any means the easiest way to do this.**

I need the remote desktop connection to "appear" as if it is coming from `devilsmilk`. But I want `duclaw` to send the response directly back to `kgraves-pc` without going through `devilsmilk`.  So to `kgraves-pc` the `RDP` session is being sent to the `localhost` which is then forwarded via `ssh` tunnel through `devilsmilk` to `duclaw`, but the `RDP` packets that are being received in response to that connection are received directly from `Duclaw`.

My commands are as follows and all of them are performed from the exact same `CYGWIN` `ssh` console on `kgraves-pc` except for the `mstsc` connection which I did from another `CYGWIN` terminal on `kgraves-pc`:

```
CNO\kgraves@KGRAVES ~
$ ssh -vg -L 3333:localhost:6666 misfitred@devilsmilk
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to devilsmilk [10.0.10.121] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
key_read: uudecode devilsmilk ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAwVZRlnAgPRPxTx           cbTPALg5XPpOnAMhJabQ3Dv/7a95eqe5l7XnKRciYQZ41B61DRgXCzC/M9ObknMR79zG0mkSl+jQTGJ7           klol7nw0+U1dNFknv4fOn+YGAsqECclWEow3OK5xRcla5eBekRGWjrZ7Wbs4F3FeKGQNqU/OuGvdSaQb           3nqgLPGTZfRhNtykQvpNzXw5cjO7XvM0BBv9di4JblLx9Fk3iq2KwdgWmK9uFDPYjU1gkHR8hk+bns1t           16KFcyDKnzhR1CblU6JT/wlBtnFa11no1UJBEHC2UQy8trwkMU6NqUt0X+D/XqW5F6+uWNc/dY97CCky           9HdfWNGQ==
 failed
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA b5:d6:eb:64:50:2f:40:04:32:10:bb:4f:a8:d3:f5:37
key_read: uudecode devilsmilk ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAwVZRlnAgPRPxTx           cbTPALg5XPpOnAMhJabQ3Dv/7a95eqe5l7XnKRciYQZ41B61DRgXCzC/M9ObknMR79zG0mkSl+jQTGJ7           klol7nw0+U1dNFknv4fOn+YGAsqECclWEow3OK5xRcla5eBekRGWjrZ7Wbs4F3FeKGQNqU/OuGvdSaQb           3nqgLPGTZfRhNtykQvpNzXw5cjO7XvM0BBv9di4JblLx9Fk3iq2KwdgWmK9uFDPYjU1gkHR8hk+bns1t           16KFcyDKnzhR1CblU6JT/wlBtnFa11no1UJBEHC2UQy8trwkMU6NqUt0X+D/XqW5F6+uWNc/dY97CCky           9HdfWNGQ==
 failed
The authenticity of host 'devilsmilk (10.0.10.121)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b5:d6:eb:64:50:2f:40:04:32:10:bb:4f:a8:d3:f5:37.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'devilsmilk' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to devilsmilk ([10.0.10.121]:22).
debug1: Local connections to *:3333 forwarded to remote address localhost:6666
debug1: Local forwarding listening on :: port 3333.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 0.0.0.0 port 3333.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Wed Jan 30 16:13:02 2013 from kgraves.cno.local
[misfitred@devilsmilk ~]$ ssh -vg -L 6666:localhost:1337 kgraves@duclaw
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to duclaw [10.0.10.120] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/misfitred/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'duclaw' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/misfitred/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/misfitred/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Next authentication method: password
kgraves@duclaw's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to *:6666 forwarded to remote address localhost:1337
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 0.0.0.0 port 6666.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on :: port 6666.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Wed Jan 30 15:55:29 2013 from devilsmilk.cno.local
"tty" option detected in CYGWIN environment variable.
CYGWIN=tty is no longer supported.  Please remove it from your
CYGWIN environment variable and use a terminal emulator like mintty,
xterm, or rxvt.

kgraves@DUCLAW ~
$ ssh -vg -R 3333:devilsmilk:6666 kgraves@kgraves
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to kgraves [10.0.10.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA de:1c:37:d7:84:0b:f8:f9:5e:da:11:49:57:4f:b8:f1
debug1: Host 'kgraves' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kgraves/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/kgraves/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interacti           ve
debug1: Next authentication method: password
kgraves@kgraves's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to kgraves ([10.0.10.113]:22).
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:3333 forwarded to local address devils           milk:6666
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen 3333, connect devilsmilk:6666
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 3333
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
Last login: Wed Jan 30 16:21:12 2013 from duclaw.cno.local
"tty" option detected in CYGWIN environment variable.
CYGWIN=tty is no longer supported.  Please remove it from your
CYGWIN environment variable and use a terminal emulator like mintty,
xterm, or rxvt.
_____________________________________________________________________________
##From separate CYGWIN Terminal##
CNO\kgraves@KGRAVES ~
$ mstsc /v:localhost:3333 /f

CNO\kgraves@KGRAVES ~
$
_____________________________________________________________________________

kgraves@KGRAVES ~
$ debug1: Connection to port 3333 forwarding to localhost port 6666 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 6666 forwarding to localhost port 1337 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3333 for localhost port 66                          66, connect from ::1 port 49496, nchannels 5
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 6666 for localhost port 13                          37, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 48808, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 3333 forwarding to localhost port 6666 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 6666 forwarding to localhost port 1337 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
$ debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3333 for localhost port 6666, conne               ct from ::1 port 49495, nchannels 5
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 6666 for localhost port 1337, connect                from 127.0.0.1 port 48807, nchannels 5
$
```

Remote Desktop Connection Established. And as you can see it looks as if it is coming from `devilsmilk` on `duclaw`. But according to `kgraves-PC` it is coming back from `Devilsmilk`.  So what I previously thought was happening actually wasn't. I thought `Duclaw` was sending the `RDP` session back to `kgraves` through a separate path but it turns out it wasn't.  I'm not sure if it was working last time and I had a different set up or if I was imagining things. But now that I got it all reconfigured and back up and running after my issue with my ssh servers it is definitely not doing that anymore.

[image]

This is `wireshark` running on `kgraves-pc` during the `RDP` session:

[image]

So my problem still remains that I want Duclaw to send the RDP session back to Kgraves-pc through a entirely separate reverse tunnel.  That is what I need to happen and can't figure out how to do.

Not only do I need `duclaw` to send it back in a separate tunnel straight to `kgraves-pc` without going through `devilsmilk` but I also need to control what Ephemeral port it sends it to. I want it to send it to port `:44444` instead of a random ephemeral port. It is using `:48809` randomly in the verbose debug `ssh` print out above.

Hopefully this clears it up, if not...sorry for confusing you even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Request

> I need the remote desktop connection to "appear" as if it is coming from devilsmilk. But I want duclaw to send the response directly back to kgraves-pc without going through devilsmilk. So to kgraves-pc the RDP session is being sent to the localhost which is then forwarded via ssh tunnel through devilsmilk to duclaw, but the RDP packets that are being received in response to that connection are received directly from Duclaw.

### Answer - No doable due to nature of TCP communication

I do not think that is doable, at least not with ssh tunnel only.

Lets look at the packet flow wanted/requested:

1. kgraves-pc start RDP request to localhost:3333, which is a tunnel to devilsmilk:6666
2. devilsmilk:6666 in turn tunnel to duclaw:1337
3. duclaw:1337 RDP reply packet send to kgraves-pc

The above packet flow will not happen, at least not under normal circumstances. Lets give the above flow a bit more details:

1. kgraves-pc start RDP request to localhost:3333, which is a tunnel to devilsmilk:6666

   At this point, kgraves-pc RDP client expect return packet coming from localhost:3333, nothing else.
2. devilsmilk:6666 in turn tunnel to duclaw:1337

   At this point, to duclaw RDP server, the request is from localhost(duclaw ifself), and it will reply directly to it.
3. duclaw:1337 RDP reply packet send to kgraves-pc

   Base on (2) above, this path is not happening at all.

### Original Answer (Not what OP want)

On `kgraves-pc`, SSH command with tunnelling to achieve OP requirement.

```
ssh user@devilsmilk -L 3333:localhost:3389 -L 6666:10.0.10.130:3389 -R 23389:localhost:3389
```

`-L 3333:localhost:3389` enable kgraves-pc RDP to devilsmilk with `localhost:3333`

`-L 6666:10.0.10.130:3389` enable kgraves-pc RDP to duclaw with `localhost:6666`

`-R 23389:localhost:3389` enable duclaw  RDP to kgraves-pc with `devilsmilk:23389`

Comment: I understand that you do not need two tunnels.  This is more of a theoretical experiment I am doing for a Network Exploitation Class I am going to be teaching. As a "malicious" user there are times you want to send data a different direction then the way you came in.  So I am trying to make Duclaw Callback to Kgraves-pc through a separate tunnel on a port that I specify because I need control.  Hopefully that might clear it up.

Comment: OK, I will add the `-R rules to enable that.

Comment: `-R` added and also modified the answer format for easier reading.

Comment: I further expanded on my question above.  I think you are misunderstanding exactly what I am trying to do.  Though I do appreciate your help.  This is a hard thing to communicate in a way that I think people can understand it.

Comment: I think I am getting it after reading the updated info. Need a bit more time to put all the tunnel together.

Comment: Yeah I am the one having to do it and it's hard for ME to follow...lol.

Comment: I was wondering if modifying the `CallbackNumber` via `Regedit.exe` located in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp` has something to do with specifying what port `RDP` calls back on. But I'm not sure how to set it.

Comment: I updated my answer.  In shot, I don't think it is doable with ssh tunnel.

Comment: I do see what you are talking about, and it makes sense.  What doesn't make sense is when I had it up and running I had `wireshark` running on `Duclaw` and on `Kgraves-PC`.  According to Wireshark Duclaw was getting SSH traffic from Devilsmilk with the RDP session inside of it like you said above.  BUT On Kgraves-PC I had SSH traffic coming straight from Duclaw at 10.0.10.130.  How would I be seeing traffic from Duclaw on Kgraves-PC then?  I'm gonna do some more experimenting with it and figure it out.  But if this isn't possible with SSH-Tunnel alone, what tools could I use?

Comment: Is Duclaw<-->Kgraves-PC traffic heavy or light? If it is light, it can be random broadcast or ssh keep-alive or something.

Comment: To do what you are asking, the only method I can think of is to write a custom rdp proxy and run on both kgraves-pc and duclaw.

Comment: Now I am by far no genius when it comes to this.  But evidently according to my Trainer (Who is a genius).  By the nature of the RFC for 127.0.0.1 (Localhost) the TCP three-way handshake never leaves layer 4 of the OSI model and it has some sort of "features" built into it that preclude the syn syn-ack ack requirement when connecting to 127.0.0.1.  Therefore TCP doesn't quite follow the same rules when connected to localhost.  He said if you could write a "wireshark" type program to sniff at layer 4 and watch the connection establish you would see what he's talking about.

Comment: The traffic is heavy.  I even tested it.  The traffic completely stops almost if there is no interaction with the Remote Desktop Connection window.  As soon as I move my mouse around or start interacting with the Remote Desktop the SSH traffic from Duclaw picks up heavy again.

Comment: He said there is a "virus" that I can use to do this, my job is to find out exactly which virus can do this re-direct for me and try to obtain it.  His method of teaching is really "obscur" if you can't already tell.  He gives me a task and answers almost zero questions and expects me to be self efficient. Whether I figure this out or not I really appreciate your effort in assisting me John Siu.

Comment: O, I misunderstand your previous comment again. For both Duclaw and Kgraves-PC, the RDP traffic is to and from localhost(127.0.0.1), that is how tunneling work. So heavy traffic is correct. Your tunneling setup works, just the packet flow is not what you wanted. (1) You want rdp packet from Kgraves-Pc to duclaw go through tunnel, this is working. (2) You want rdp packet from dclaw to kgraves-pc go outside the tunnel, that is not working. The packet is using the tunnel. That is why you see traffic.

Comment: I believe the virus your instructor talk about has the capability to do packet routing, the same idea of a custom rdp proxy, in a sneakier way.

Comment: 'BUT On Kgraves-PC I had SSH traffic coming straight from Duclaw at 10.0.10.130.' I will have to go trace through your tunnel setup again on paper, I think that is because the way your tunnel is setup.

Comment: Exactly. They are both talking to `localhost` so I have `localhost` on `duclaw` forwarding traffic it receives on RDP port `1337` to `kgraves-pc`.  Or at least I think this is what is happening, but to be honest I'm just confused at this point.  I need to take a step back and look at this more and figure out what it is that I am missing or what I need to do before I start looking into any virus or proxy. I feel like the `ssh -R 3333:DEVILSMILK:6666 kgraves@kgraves-PC` command isn't right.  I feel like this is redundant becuase `kgraves-pc` is already forwarding `3333` to `devilksmilk` `6666`.

Comment: First things first.  As you can see from my other Question you commented on. In order to test any of this I have to get it set up again.  But for some reason I can't SSH into Devilsmilk...which is another mystery in itself.  I'm all screwed up. lol

Comment: It is not redundant, but it is not being used.

Comment: lol, i will look at that too. Got to go out now.

Comment: Please use [chat] for extended discussion.

Comment: Added further information to my question with verbose ssh print out.

Comment: I know why `Duclaw<-->Kgraves-PC` has heavy ssh traffic. But this is getting too long here. Create a new question and I will answer there.